# expected distance in 2D

Tags: absolute-value, expected-value

Suppose there are two jumping children. One randomly chooses positions ($x_1,y_1$) and ($x_2,y_2$). The other randomly chooses the positions ($x_3, y_3$) and ($x_4, y_4$). What is the average distance between the two children (exact solution)? Kindly ask for a hint.

Comment: How do you mean "randomly chooses positions $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$"? Are the $x_i$ and $y_i$ given and fixed and the child randomly chooses one of these two given positions with equal probability $\frac12$? If so, the average distance is trivially a quarter of the sum of the four pair distances. Or does the child randomly choose the $x_i$ and $y_i$, as a literal interpretation of your formulation would suggest? If so, according to which distribution does it choose these positions, and how does it choose which one to occupy?

Comment: you are right. I forgot to mention that that the points are fixed. So child 1 chooses randomly either point $P_1 = (x_1,y_1)$ or $P_2 = x_2,y_2)$ with probabiity 1/2. The distance between these two points is $d_1 = \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$. The other child chooses either$P_3$ or $P_4$, also with prob. 1/2.  The task is to find the expected relative distance between the two children.

Answer (score 0):

Each of the four pair of points has the same probability $\frac14$ to occur, so the expected distance is

$$
\frac14\left(d_{13}+d_{14}+d_{23}+d_{24}\right)\;,
$$

where $d_{jk}=\sqrt{(x_j-x_k)^2+(y_j-y_k)^2}$.